# How to list docker image repositories using registry http api v2?

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I am trying to fetch the list of repositry inside a docker registry using api version 2.

My target is to fetch the repositories from docker hub which is owned by me.

First I used basic authentication to get bearer token from authentication server "https://auth.docker.io/token?service=registry.docker.io"

Then i made a call to get the list of repo using this bearer token "https://index.docker.io/v2/_catalog" . But i am getting unauthorised error. Any idea whay could be the reason.

Comment: How did you pass the auth to the second call?

Comment: Bearer <token i received from first call>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that while the call to get the list of repositories is correct this api is intentionally blocked in dockerhub. Docker hub has huge list of repository, and probably due to this reason they have blocked this called. Alternatively you can use search api from docker v1.

Answer (score 0):

Went thru the [GOLang code](https://github.com/docker/docker-registry) and found the API follows [RFC 2616 section 14.8](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html). The security uses HTTP Authorization header with 'Basic' authentication token.

Example using PowerShell to list repostories.

1. Use docker CLI to make the credentials

   docker login --username myuseraccount --password secretpassword

   cat ([IO.Path]::Combine($env:USERPROFILE,  '.docker\config.json'))
2. Copy the basic token from the config.json to clipboard.
3. List Your Azure respositories. The space between Basic and base64 encoded token is needed.

   Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://*YOURAZUREREGISTY*.azurecr.io/v2/_catalog -Method Get -Headers @{'Authorization'='Basic *PASTEBASE64BASICTOKENFROM2*'}

Answer (score 0):

Using cURL:

```
curl https://<REGISTRY URL>/v2/_catalog -H 'Authorization: Basic <AUTH TOKEN>'
```

Where the auth token can be taken from `~/.docker/config.json` (after you've done `docker login` if necessary)

And to list tags:

```
curl https://<REGISTRY URL>/v2/<REPO>/tags/list -H 'Authorization: Basic <AUTH TOKEN>'
```